# Numerical Approxmation of standard errors for parameter estimation in the EM algorithm

Tags: standard-error, expectation-maximization, information-theory, fisher-information

Generally, when you want to compute standard errors for estimated parameters within the ML framework, one uses the diagonal elements of the observed information matrix. In for instance `R`'s `optim`, this is obtained directly by the Hessian argument.

However, in the EM algorithm, the MLE is obtained from an augmented data set. The standard errors for this setting cannot be directly calculated from the hessian. It is suggested that the information matrix of the complete data $I_c$ has to be adjusted for the missing information.

In McLachlan and Peel's Finite Mixture Models, they state that the observed information is found by

$I(\hat{\Theta};y) = I_c(\hat{\Theta};y)-E\Big[S_c(Y_c;\Theta)S_c^T(Y_c;\Theta)|y\Big]_{\Theta=\hat{\Theta}}$

where $\Theta$ is the vector of parameters, $y$ the observed data and $S_c(Y_c;\Theta)$ the complete score-statistics.

Practically, $I_c$ is obtained easily from the Hessian argument as mentioned previously. The second term is somewhat more complicated. If the expression is analytically intractable, is there an easy way to numerically estimate it instead?

Comment: Side stepping the question, but is the observed likelihood function tractable? Because if so, then you could easily compute the Hessian of the  observed likelihood function at the MLE and not need to compute $S_c(Y_c; \Theta)$.

Comment: P.S. if the observed likelihood is intractable, I know that we still can get a numeric approximation of the observed Hessian, but my understand is that it's not simple by any means. If you are really curious, I believe the paper below addresses the issue (disclosure: have not read).

"Using EM to obtain asymptotic variancecovariance matrices The SEM algorithm" by Meng and Rubin

Comment: That is a good point, the observed likelihood function is not analytically tractable, but numerically so. Indeed that is the simplest solution, thank you!